# Is it possible to calculate the zoom level from fitBounds() of getBounds() in Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, leaflet

I'm trying to improve the user experience (flyTo animations) with featureGroup (markers) and pan the user to the appropriate zoom level and position on the map.

I can calculate the centre point of a feature group after running the getBounds(), but i cannot calculate the zoom level to know what zoom factor to use in the flyTo() animation.

```
 markerGroup = L.featureGroup( arrMarkers );
 mapLibObj.fitBounds( markerGroup.getBounds() );
```

It's overkill to create a "hidden" leaflet map purely for these type of calculations, i wish there was a function like "calculateBounds()" that returned the extent + zoom values for my next step ...

Comment: I think you overlooked [`flyToBounds()`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#map-flytobounds). See also [`getBoundsZoom()`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#map-getboundszoom).

Comment: Yes i did! Thank you @IvanSanchez